# Junit testing correct log output from method?

Tags: java, logging, junit, int, slf4j

I have the following simple `method` within my `Java` Application:

**Method I wish to test:**

```
 public void showOutputOfIdentifications(int age) {

    if(age>25){

        LOGGER.info("Over 25");

    }else{

        LOGGER.info("25 or Under");

    }
 }
```

How can I test this method to ensure it is logging what it should if a value is over/under 25?

For reference: I am currently using the `Junit` framework with `Mockito`. My logger is `slf4j`.

Comment: Look http://www.coderanch.com/t/96469/Testing/junit-asserts-log-Messages maybe this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided LOGGER is an object, the classic way is to replace it with a mock. [Mockito](http://mockito.org) is a well known mock library, but other are around, just pick one. With mockito, it could look like:

```
LOGGER_mock = mock(LoggerClass.class);
// inject LOGGER_mock into class to test, eventually use reflection to change
//  a private attribute

classToTest.showOutputOfIdentifications(10);
verify(LOGGER_mock).info("25 or Under");
```